Why is the firebase message service not working?
My problem is that I don't receive the push message sent and I don't get an error after which I could start and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
It is important that I am building a flutter application, the code runs without errors and what I wanted so far works, but the push message does not.
What I've done so far.
The libraries I use:
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
sign_in_with_apple: ^6.1.0
flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
http: ^1.2.1
google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
firebase_core: ^3.0.0
firebase_auth: ^5.0.0
firebase_analytics: ^11.0.0
firebase_messaging: ^15.0.0
geolocator: ^12.0.0

The application accepts push messages. At Apple, I enabled all the services requested in the description.
What's next? How can I check if there is an error?
I start firebase here, it is important to note that analytics is working, I can see it even if I am active on the firebase admin page.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  await FirebaseNotifications().initNotifications();
  await FirebaseNotifications().setupInteractedMessage();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

firebase_notification.dart file contains:
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('title: ${message.notification?.title}');
}

class FirebaseNotifications {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(provisional: true);

    String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('Token: $token');
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    final apnsToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
    if (apnsToken != null) {
      print('apns true');
    } else {
      print('apns false');
    }
  }

  Future<String?> getFirebaseToken() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    return token;
  }

  Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
  }

  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message == null) return;
  }

  Future handleBackgroundNotification() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
  }
}

The apn and token generation also works.
AppDelegate.swift contains:
import UIKit
import Flutter
//import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    //FirebaseApp.configure()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

I don't use what I commented here, as far as I know it is no longer necessary. But when I used it, I got this error message: PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

Make sure you have the correct permissions set in your Info.plist file.
